# How can I fit images into circles without stretching?

Tags: html, css

For example I have such images:

[image]
[image]

and css:

```
.company-header-avatar{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    border-radius: 60px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    margin: 7px 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

As the result I get:

[image]

But they are stretched. Are there any ways to make them rounded, but without stretching? (for example, get part from middle, etc)

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/73h7try9/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I recommend applying the images with `background-image` to a div and then applying `background-size: cover` to ensure the ratio stays correct regardless of the image's original size/ratio:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73h7try9/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="company-header-avatar" style="background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/6E06C3D.jpeg)"></div>

<div class="company-header-avatar" style="background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/8WluhcUlWl8.jpg)"></div>
```

CSS

```
.company-header-avatar{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    border-radius: 60px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    margin: 7px 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: can i somehow get it from center? i mean i have image 3:2 and i get square 1:1 from center?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 You can add `background-position: center center;`. Answer and fiddle updated.

Answer (score 4):

This did the work for me.

```css
.company-header-avatar{
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: @Alex When we use `contain`, the replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting within the element's content box

Answer (score 1):

if you use jquery than check this `jsfiddle.` : http://jsfiddle.net/73h7try9/2/

you js should:

```
$('.image_cover').each(function(){
var imageWidth = $(this).find('img').width();
var imageheight = $(this).find('img'). height();
  if(imageWidth > imageheight){
    $(this).addClass('landscape');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('potrait');
  }
})
```

your css should :

```
.company-header-avatar{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
 }
 .landscape .company-header-avatar{ 
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
 }
 .potrait .company-header-avatar{ 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
 .image_cover{ 
    width:60px; 
    height:60px; 
    border-radius:50%; 
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;    
    margin: 7px 0 0 5px;
 }
```

your html should:

```
 <div class="image_cover">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/6E06C3D.jpeg" class="company-header-avatar">
 </div>

<div class="image_cover">
   <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/8WluhcUlWl8.jpg" class="company-header-avatar">
</div>
```

Comment: can i somehow get it from center? i mean i have image 3:2 and i get square 1:1 from center?

Comment: so, what about my second question?

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS is sufficient :

```
.profile-avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

And the usage in html :

```
<img class="profile-avatar"  src="{{ user.picture }}" style="width: 1.5em; height: 1.5em;">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to wrap the image in an element you could try `display:flex` and `align-items: center` on the parent element.