# How do I make Bootstrap image rounded?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I cannot seem to get my images in a perfect circle using:

```
.rounded {
    border-radius: 50px!important;
}
```

Is there another CSS setting I should use? The top and bottom of the image still have a horizontal line, even if I raise more than 50px.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In a comment you said _"when I used width/height/border-radius, it does make the image circular, but it does not maintain aspect ratio."_ — if you change the height/width of an image then you _**are**_ changing the aspect ratio. If you want to maintain the aspect ratio you will have to _clip_ the image; if you make the image square and set a `border-radius: 50%` it will be a circle. The size of the radius you need depends on the size of the element, so you're better off using 50% than calculating the pixel value required, which changes if the box changes.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using bootstrap simply use class .rounded-circle

```
<img src="img.jpg" class="rounded-circle" alt="img">
```

you can use this css property as well

```
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
```

Comment: It does an oblique circle and not completely round.

Comment: use the above mentioned CSS property in style tag

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.rounded{
  border-radius:50% !important; 
 }
```

Pixel values don't contribute much in terms of enhancement such in your case. Use % instead. You will get fully rounded shape the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **border-radius:50px** prefer to use border-radius:**50% or 100px**.
I have attach the snippet as a example. Please feel free to comment if you still face an issue.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Rounded Images</h2>

<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7f/24/d8/7f24d81c34fc9ed92e5d1a71c1969d36.png" style="width:100px; border: 2px solid black;">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of structure is image in ? If it is in a card structure, each card for bootstrap comes with certain settings automatically. If you are using a card, you can try removing the borders that are exclusive to the card. Like:

```
.card{
 border: 0;  
}
```

If you just want the picture to be completely round, you need to define the width and height values the same. Like:

```
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border:radius: 50%;
```

If your problems are not one of them please share more information and code.

Comment: It's not in a Bootstrap card. My issue is that when I used width/height/border-radius, it does make the image circular, but it does not maintain aspect ratio. It squashes the image inwards.

Comment: I see that this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477563/css-fit-rounded-circle-image-do-not-stretch-it

Comment: Look it up, and if you can't crack it, throw out all your codes. I won't be able to say anything until I see all your codes.

Comment: CanUver - Can I add you to the private repo?